# How to disable css validation border

Tags: jquery, css

I am developing a JQuery function that disable a TextBox field when a second field is filled and the opposite is true.

In other words, it restrict the input to only one field.

The problem that when I test one of the two field (which the input is only restricted to Numbers) with a caractere, and then I make it again empty and go to the field, the red border still showed around the first field although it has been disabled.

I tried to remove rules but it didn't work.

Code:

```
 $("#FirstId").on('input', function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $('#SecondId').prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $('#SecondId').prop("disabled", false);

        }
    })

    $("#SecondId").on('input', function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $('#FirstId').prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $('#FirstId').prop("disabled", false);
        }
    })

    $("#SecondId").on('input', function ClearValidation() {

            $('#FirstId').rules('remove');

    })
```

Comment: I see a place where you add a disabled class (`.addClass("disabled")`), but where do you remove/toggle it?

Comment: @zgood oh sorry that's was try that I forget to remove it, I will update the code again sorry

Comment: When do you want red border to appear, its not clear

Comment: @BhushanBabar the red border will appear automatically when I try to enter a NO NUMBER in the field (validation) but it still appared although the field will empty again

Comment: none of this code does anything with borders. Can we see the relevant HTML and CSS please

Comment: @ADyson ok I will add it rightnow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the [jQuery-Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin because of the `rules` you're trying to remove... You should have mentionned the usage of the plugin.

I made something that might be close to what you have regarding the markup... And I significantly "reduced" your code. Have a look:

```js
var first = $('#FirstId');
var second = $('#SecondId');

first.on('input', function () {
  // Enable/disable the other input
  second.prop("disabled", $(this).val() != "");
});

second.on('input', function() {
  // Enable/disable the other input
  first.prop("disabled", $(this).val() != "");
  // Remove validation error
  first.removeClass('error');
  first.next("label.error").remove();
});

$("#myForm").validate({
  rules:{
    FirstId: "number"
  }
});
```

```css
input.error{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <input id="FirstId" name="FirstId" required><br>
  <input id="SecondId" name="SecondId" required><br>
</form>
```

So type a letter in the `#FirstId`... Then remove it. It will show an error message about "required". Then type in `#SecondId`. The previous error is now removed.

Answer (score 2):

Is this how you want it to be? If you don't want red border when its disabled just remove invalid class when you disabled that input

```js
$("#FirstId").on('input', function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $("#FirstId").removeClass("disabled");
        $("#SecondId").removeClass("invalid");
            $('#SecondId').prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $('#SecondId').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
          $("#FirstId").addClass("invalid");
        } else {
          $("#FirstId").removeClass("invalid");
        }
    })

    $("#SecondId").on('input', function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $("#FirstId").removeClass("invalid");
            $('#FirstId').prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
        
            $('#FirstId').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
          $("#SecondId").addClass("invalid");
        } else {
          $("#SecondId").removeClass("invalid");
        }
    })
```

```css
.invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="FirstId">
<input type="number" id="SecondId">
```

Comment: @AmmoPT what exactly is not working? would you explain?

Comment: It's activating the invalid class - and maintaining it - when it's empty, after having had values.

Comment: I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L3m86fdj/2/) is what he wants, but his other code is interfering with it.

Comment: @AmmoPT he wants to show red border when the field is left empty, but if user starts typing in another field he wants to remove border from first field and disable it. Thats what I have assumed from his post.

Comment: @BhusanBabar I think you're right, I might've misunderstood the question. Apologies.